# Reading array JSON with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the next array json, How could I read it?
I already tried with `document.write(arr)`, and it works, but If I put `document.write(arr[0].Category)` it shows `undefined`,

```
var arr = [{"Category":
{"cell":{"question1":{"que1":"What is the cell?"},
"option1":{"op1":"The cell is the basic structural and functional unit",
"op2":"is a fictional supervillain in Dragon Ball"},"answer1":"opt1"}}},
{"Category":{"Mars":{"question1":{"que1":"How many moons does Mars?"},
"option1":{"op1":"5","op2":"2"},"answer1":"opt2"}}}]
```

By the way the array is well formet, because if I do `document.write(arr)` it return the same array

Comment: It should work fine. `document.write()` is not the best way to inspect variables. Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: That's not a JSON string, but a simple object/array literal!

Comment: Can you make a demo that shows what `document.write(arr)` actually prints?

Comment: it prints the same array [{"Category":
{"cell":{"question1":{"que1":"What is the cell?"},...........

Comment: i need to say, que the array was extracted of json file, and I did a var arr = JSON.stringify(arrjson)

Comment: Then use `arrjson[0].Category` instead. `arr` is a string.

Comment: arr is not a string in the code given, @chikatetsu where did you do `var arr = JSON.stringify(arrjson)`? This conflicts with the code you have given.

Comment: @popnoodles yeah you right, now it works, I deleted var arr = JSON.stringify(arrjson), and I just put document.write(arrjson[0].Category)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does work. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/5GTWp/

```
console.log(arr[0].Category);
document.write(arr[0].Category.cell.question1.que1);
```

Logs the object, 
writes: `What is the cell?`

```
document.write(arr[0].Category)
```

writes `[object Object]`, not undefined.

Problem is not in the code given.

EDIT: Further information. OP has added in a comment *"i need to say, que the array was extracted of json file, and I did a var arr = JSON.stringify(arrjson)"*

If you make arr a string it's not going to work. The example you gave != your problem.

```
document.write(arrjson[0].Category);
```

is the object you are looking for.